# Xamarin Android - Oxyplot, hide axis values

Tags: xamarin.android, oxyplot

I am developing a xamarin android app and I am using oxyplot to display a graph. This is the code of oxyplot

```
        OxyPlot.Axes.CategoryAxis xaxis = new OxyPlot.Axes.CategoryAxis();
        xaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Bottom;
        xaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Transparent;
        xaxis.IsPanEnabled = false;
        xaxis.IsAxisVisible = false;
        xaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
        xaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
        xaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
        xaxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
        xaxis.IsPanEnabled = false;


        LinearAxis yaxis = new LinearAxis();
        yaxis.Position = AxisPosition.Left;
        yaxis.TextColor = OxyColors.Transparent;
        yaxis.IsPanEnabled = false;
        yaxis.IsAxisVisible = false;
        yaxis.MinorTickSize = 0;
        yaxis.MajorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
        yaxis.MinorGridlineStyle = LineStyle.None;
        yaxis.IsZoomEnabled = false;
        yaxis.IsPanEnabled = false;

        OxyPlot.Series.ColumnSeries s1 = new OxyPlot.Series.ColumnSeries();
        //s1.IsStacked = true;
        s1.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(100));
        s1.Items.Add(new ColumnItem(55));



        var model = new PlotModel();
        model.Background = OxyColors.White;
        model.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;

        model.Series.Add(s1);
        model.IsLegendVisible = false;

        return model;
```

And this is the output in my phone

[image]

The problem is that I wanna hide everything except the two bars. Hide the lines and the values of the axis. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the [documentation](http://docs.oxyplot.org/en/latest/models/axes/):

> If no axes are defined, linear axes will be added to the bottom and left.

You have not set these two axes to your model, so it adds two default axes.
You could try to use the following codes to add axes:

```
//...
//Your other code
//....

var model = new PlotModel();
model.Background = OxyColors.White;
model.PlotAreaBorderColor = OxyColors.Transparent;

//Add axes
model.Axes.Add(xaxis);
model.Axes.Add(yaxis);

model.Series.Add(s1);
model.IsLegendVisible = false;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Works.